# Unable to find declaration of 'beans' element in spring mvc portlet

Tags: spring-mvc, xml-parsing, applicationcontext, spring-portlet-mvc, liferay-dxp

We have created a Spring mvc portlet with given application context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

On deploying the portlet,the below error message is thrown:

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber:
>   64; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.    at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
>
> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 6 in XML document from PortletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/portletpreferences-portlet.xml] is invalid; nested
>   exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6;
>   columnNumber: 64; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element
>   'beans'.

The respective spring jars are available to the project as dependencies as shown below:
[image]

I have referred all available similar questions to this issue and tried the following:

1. Adding doctype tag
2. Removing xsd version
3. Using an empty  elements with beans tag

Are there still any missing dependecies or errors in xml in context xml file.

**Update**: I have updated both spring beans and spring context jars to same version and also successfullly validated the xml file with xsd definition,but am still getting the same error post deployment.

Comment: try to replace `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd` with `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd`,and `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd` with `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd` and see once

Comment: I was previously using the same way only but with same error.